# Feedzirra crashes with error msg "Trace/BPT trap"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, feedzirra

I have a brand new app, where I have installed feedzirra; my gem file looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pauldix-feedzirra'
gem 'taf2-curb'
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
  require 'feedzirra'
  feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse("http://feed.com/feed.xml")
```

When i start the server it looks fine until i load the page with the controller and the server shuts down with the message

> Trace/BPT trap

Any suggestions to how I solve this?

--
Issue solved; following this: http://tmonrails.blogspot.com/2010/07/feedzirra-on-rails-3.html

Comment: is that all? do you have more trace? what web server do you use? btw, gems in Gemfile are auto loaded, the require is uneccesary.

Comment: I use WEBrick, and this is all the error msg i get:
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-04-28 17:38:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-04-28 17:38:00] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-02-18) [x86_64-darwin10]
[2011-04-28 17:38:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5869 port=3000
Trace/BPT trap

Comment: updated my feedzirra.rb file as described here: [link](http://procbits.com/2011/01/25/feedzirra-and-rails-3/) now it seems to work in console but the server still crashes...